# Conky New Line Problems

Tags: conky

I have the following conkyrc

```
use_xft yes
xftfont profont:size=8
override_utf8_locale yes

update_interval 1
total_run_times 0

own_window yes
own_window_type panel
own_window_hints undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

background yes

# Eliminate flickering
double_buffer yes

# Use KiB/MiB/... instead of just bytes
format_human_readable yes
# Print used memory with buffers
no_buffers no
# Display k, G, ... instead of kiB, GiB, ...
short_units yes

#use_spacer left
#if_up_strictness address
#pad_percents 2

alignment top_left
gap_x 1000
gap_y 5

default_graph_size 8 30

# Blue color theme
# color0 D0D0D0
# color1 009DD8
# color2 fbb117
# default_color d0d0d0
# own_window_colour 1c1c1c

# lb.theme
color0 D0D0D0
color1 1AA
default_color D0D0D0
own_window_colour 333

TEXT
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${cpu}%  \
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${exec sensors | grep -n 'temp1' | sed -n 2p | awk -F'+' '{print $2}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'}  \
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${mem}/${memmax}  \
${font profont:size=8}${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${fs_used_perc /}%  \
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${if_up enp3s0f1}${addrs enp3s0f1}${else}DOWN${endif}  \
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} ${color0} ${font profont:size=8}${if_up wlp4s0}${wireless_essid wlp4s0} [${addrs wlp4s0}]${else}DOWN${endif}  \
${if_empty ${exec acpi -b | grep Discharging}} ${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9}\
${else}\
${if_match ${battery_percent} >= 90} ${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${else}\
${if_match ${battery_percent} >= 65} ${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${else}\
${if_match ${battery_percent} >= 35} ${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${else}\
${if_match ${battery_percent} >= 10} ${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${else}\
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${endif}\
${endif}\
${endif}\
${endif}\
${endif}\
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${battery_percent BAT0}%  \
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${exec ~/Repos/TacoDot/herbstluftwm/volume.sh}  \
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${time %R}  \
${color1}${font FontAwesome:size=9} \
${font profont:size=8}${color0}${time %a %d.%m.%Y}
```

Unfortunately, the different parts that should be all in one single line, seem to gradually shift downwards like they would be treated as new lines. What am I missing here? I thought that the backslash is an escape for newlines.

I am running Conky in version 1.10.1 on an Ubuntu 16.04